# submenu inside li affecting due to style of li on active of a

Tags: javascript

I have li menu and inside that , there is a submenu again for li.

Now on change of a of main li, when I change style of li , its affecting to all submenus as well.

Is there any solution?

Thanks

Comment: please post some sample code to better show your issue.

Answer (score 1):

**I would use one of these selectors:**

- CSS .class Selector - http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_class.asp
- CSS #id Selector - http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_id.asp
- CSS3 :nth-child() Selector - http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp

Please, read more about CSS selectors here:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp